# Jmeter Headless browser load testing

Tags: java, selenium, junit, jmeter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nGV4.png)Trying to execute junit with headless browser[phantomjs], have the required phantomjs jars in lib and when trying to open page its throwing error.It is just a pure selenium code in junit.

```
    System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", "D:\\Jmeter\\phantomjs.exe");
    WebDriver driver=new PhantomJSDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.anypage.com");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='x']")).click();
    System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
    driver.quit();
```

Comment: Your example code says `HtmlUnitDriver`, that is not the same as `PhantomJSDriver`! Also, you forgot to say what the error is. If you really want help, please have a read through [mcve].

Comment: I have updated the code, error is it not executing the script in jmeter it is failing. What will be the procedure to run headless browsing in jmeter because we need to use some load of 50 to 100 users and I dont want 100 pages to open.

Comment: Need to see what the exception is that you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what's wrong without seeing your error message, my expectation is that there is a JMeter and Selenium libraries clash, both use [Apache HTTP Components](https://hc.apache.org/) but different versions.

I would suggest trying out clean JMeter installation and [WebDriver Sampler](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) plugin - this way you'll be able to keep your code in JMeter Test Plan and it will be easier to update it. There is a special config element - [PhantomJS Driver Config](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PhantomJSDriverConfig/) where you can specify path to phantomjs binary and command-line arguments if needed.

However load testing using PhantomJS might not be a very good idea, it is better to consider conducting main load using JMeter and run single browser instance in parallel to test rendering time while system is under load. If you will go that way I believe [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) will help a lot

Comment: I have added link to image, this may be helpfull, also I have added selenium jmeter addons to lib folder of jmeter and have deleted the older version jars. In addition I am also not able to find PhantomJS Driver Config

Comment: Unfortulately it doesn't tell much.